# I am stuck with that error variables 'n' and 'm' used in loop condition not modified in loop body

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{    
    // TODO: Prompt for start size
    int n,m,y,b,a;
    do{
        n= get_int("Start Size");
    }
    while(n <9);
    // TODO: Prompt for end size
    do
    {
        m = get_int("End Size");
    }
    while(n > m);
    
    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold

    for (y=0;n>m;y++)
    {
        a = n/3;
        b = n/4;
        y= n + a-b;
    }
    // TODO: Print number of years
    {
        printf("Years:%i\n",y);
    }
}
```

Please can you tell me why I get this error (variables 'n' and 'm' used in loop condition not modified in loop body)?

Comment: The problematic loop is probably `for (y=0;n>m;y++)` (which should be easy to see if we could see the actual error message, in full and complete). The variables `n` and `m` are used in the condition `n>m`, but they are never modified anywhere inside the loop. So if the condition `n>m` is true, it will stay true forever and you have an infinite loop.

Comment: The last loop use the condition `n > m`. But it only updates `a`, `b`, and `y`. So the condition won't change and the loop will execute infinitely or not at all.

Comment: On another note about that loop, you modify `y` *twice*. Once in `y= n + a-b;` and then again in `y++`.

Comment: It would help if you explained what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: Given the `do { … } while (n > m);` loop, the subsequent `for (y = 0; n > m; y++)` will never be executed.

Comment: @Barmar check this https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/labs/1/

Comment: The question should be self-contained, not rely on outside sites for important information.

Comment: Please update our question and add (a) the requirements and (b) the entire error message. Especially the line numbers in the error message are usefull

Comment: Thanks i Solve The Problem I made a Mistake I Update y Inside The loop instad of n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition to end the loop doesn't depend on anything that changes inside the loop. So the loop will either never execute or will execute forever.